# Is this a valid call/syntax in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is this a valid call/syntax in ruby?

```
ClassA.ClassB.methodOne(param)
```

Comment: It is a valid syntax, but only on the condition `ClassB` is actually a method (and not contstant/class).

Comment: It depends how you have defined `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `methodOne` and `param`. Yes, that is valid syntax that *could* be made to work. But no, that's probably the wrong way to write whatever it is you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I would strongly advise providing more context of your code (a [mcve]), so we can explain what a "good way" of doing whatever-it-is could look like.

Comment: BTW I guess it's much easier to answer this question pasteing this snippet into `irb` console. If it triggers `SyntaxError`, it's not a valid syntax. If it triggers other error or no error at all, it's a valid syntax.

Comment: Here's what I want to do.

def shift_request
    @message = @shift_request.shift.message()
  end

shift_request belongs to shift
shift has many shift_requests

but I get an error: undefined method for 'shift' though its a class and not a method of the shift_request

Answer (score 0):

As Marek Lipka and Tom Lord said, it depends if ClassA, ClassB, methodOne, and param are methods or a class. However, in ruby everything is an object. For example:

- 5 <= This is an object (Normally it would be an Integer and could not call a method)
- time <= This is a method
- puts <= Print command in ruby

All 3 combined could look like this:

```
5.time { puts "Hello you there."}
```

It will print 5 times Hello.

If you want to read more about ruby check out the documentation.
http://ruby-doc.org/

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: "it depends if ClassA, ClassB, methodOne, and param are methods or a class" – No, it doesn't. Those are all semantic distinctions, they have no bearing on whether something is valid syntax or not.